# Unable to find .git folder in my repository

Tags: .git-folder

I am creating my first local Git repository in my computer. Here in the Git terminal it is showing (Initialized empty Git repository in `C:/Users/iliyas/Desktop/Tuna/.git/`) but I am unable to see .git folder in my Tuna folder which I have created.

My Tuna folder is showing empty.

Comment: Hi .git folder will be hidden , Enable the setting to show hidden folder to view the .git folder inside your directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the version git 2.9, the  **.git** folder remains hidden by default for a purpose. if you can pull or push the data from/to the repo then it means you already have .git in the folder.

If you really want to view it as physical file then you need to enable  hidden and system files and folders in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

`.git` folder is a hidden folder. Change your folder properties to show hidden files and folders. It would show.

Comment: You can upvote or accept the answer to show appreciation ;)